# Errors while linking C++ and Fortran90 code

Tags: c++, fortran, fortran90

So I'm working on trying to link two simple codes, one in C++ and the other in Fortran90. I've spent the last few days looking around the internet and everything I've seen makes it look like what I'm doing *should* work, but I'm here so obviously it's not. Here's what I've got

C++ Code: BasicFusion.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

extern "C"
{
    void Fusion_(double *T, double *dens);
}

void Fusion_(double *T, double *dens)
{
    double dT;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("Temp.dat","a");

    dT = *dens * 1.46e-9;
    *T = *T + dT;

    cout << "The new Temperature is: " << T << endl;
    fprintf(fp, "%f \n" T);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Fortran Code: BasicHydro.f90

```
program BasicHydro
implicit none

double precision :: R
double precision :: rho
double precision :: T = 1.0d4
double precision :: M = 2.0d30
double precision :: G = 6.67d-11
double precision :: k = 1.381d-23
double precision :: pi = 3.14159265359d0
integer :: i

do i=1,10,1
    open(1,file='density.dat',action='write',position="append")
    R = (75/(4*pi))*((k*T)/(G))**2

    write(*,*) 'The new density is',rho

    write(1,*) rho
    close(1)
    call Fusion(T,rho)
end do
end program BasicHydro
```

On the command line I enter:

```
>g++ -c BasicFusion.cpp
>gfortran -c BasicHydro.f90
>gfortran -o HydroThermo BasicFusion.o BasicHydro.o -lstdc++
```

I've also used ifort in place of gfortran using the same tags and files. In both cases I get the same error:

```
BasicHydro.o: In function `MAIN__':
BasicHydro.f90:(.text+0x27d): undefined reference to `fusion_'
```

None of the examples I've seen have made a reference in the fortran code to the C++ program, while they have used the same structure to lay everything out.

Comment: Mangling the names yourself suggests that you're not familiar with Fortran's *interoperability with C* features.  Have a poke around the tag `fortran-iso-c-binding` and see what you can learn.

Comment: Use tag fortran for all Fortran questions. Fortran 90 is quite old and obsolete.

Comment: @VladimirF how I wish you were utterly right. I certainly wish F90 was old and obsolete, instead of being this "newfangled" thing that a colleague and I are trying to slowly port our company's main orbital propagation / trajectory optimization tool to. Such bleeding edge features as modules and user-defined types! No, we'd better keep using our codebase built upon tons of COMMON variables (altough I should say that at least they're organised in include files). Oh, and this wasn't code from the 70s, this was written in 2002.

Comment: @JavierMartín I'd say the "oldness" of F90 could be judged by the green covering of this Matrix: http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Fortran+2003+status, this might not cover all relevant compilers and might include some that are not too relevant, but it gives a pretty good idea of F2003 support. As long as even major compilers like GNU do not completely support F2003, F90 is not that obsolete, I'd agree. However, as you can see there, the iso-c-binding is basically supported by all compilers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my advisor just stopped by and after going through some other documentation it appears that since Fortran isn't case dependant, it automatically makes everything lower case. Since I had defined Fusion with an upper case F, the C++ object file had it with an upper F. So when I tried to run the whole thing the fortran part was looking for fusion and the c++ part only had Fusion...

moral of the story: make everything lower case all of the time.

Comment: And sometimes capital and sometimes it adds various decorations... Use `bind(C,name=)` to stay portable.